# Scala Ordered/Java Comparable interoperability

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I am trying to implement an equivalent of Guava's RangeSet in Scala (I need additional features to Guava's RangeSet such as fast intersection and full immutable implementation). However, I would like to continue using Guava's Range class as it is fairly complete and would be a pain in the ass to rewrite in Scala from scratch (BTW, this would be a nice addition to Scala's standard library).

However, I am stick with the Ordered/Comparable interoperability, especially when using type-bounds. Scala's idiomatic `[A < Ordered[A]]` is compatible with Guava's `[C <: Comparable[_]]`, but it won't work with more exotic type bounds such as `[A <% Ordered[A]]`, which is required to work with standard types such as Ints (which is my main use case of course)

In short, how to make things such as the following compile?

```
import com.google.common.collect.{ Range => GuavaRange }
def closed[A <% Ordered[A]](l: A, u: A) = GuavaRange.closed(l, u)
```

For now, I get the following error: `inferred type arguments [A] do not conform to method closed's type parameter bounds [C <: Comparable[_]]`

Replacing the `<%` operator with `<:` compiles, but the function will no longer accept Ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `A` of `closed` becomes the type parameter passed to `GuavaRange`, and therefore it must subtype `Comparable`. `Ordered` subtypes `Comparable`, so `[A <: Ordered[A]]` is fine but `<%` only declares a view bound and won't guarantee that `A` will be `Comparable`, only that a conversion to `Ordered`/`Comparable` exists.

You can't create a `GuavaRange` of type `Int` because `Int` doesn't implement `Comparable`. When autoboxed an `Int` is really a `java.lang.Integer`, but the compiler still doesn't let you treat it as `Comparable`. You'll have to choose between:

1. `java.lang.Integer`. This does implement `Comparable`, but not `Ordered`. There are implicit conversions between it and `Int`.
2. `scala.runtime.RichInt` When you implicitly convert an `Int` to an `Ordered`, this is what you get. Has implicit conversions to and from `Int`.
3. Your own wrapper.

The idiomatic Scala way to build a class like this would be for it to take an `Ordering` instance, but that would prevent you from using Guava's `Range` unless you put an extra box around everything (i.e. wrapping them in a `Comparable` that delegates to the `Ordering`).